# How do i formally show that the vectors are in a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 3a − 2b + 7c = 0\}$.

Clearly $(0,0,0) \in A$ since $3(0) -2(0) + 7(c) = 0$.

I understand the concept of showing that the set is closed under addition and closed under scalar multiplication but am a bit unsure how to formally show it.

So, if we let $\overrightarrow{u} = (a,b,c)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ then we can write: $\lambda\overrightarrow{u} = (\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)$ so $3\lambda a - 2 \lambda b +7 \lambda c = \lambda (3a-2b+7c) = 0$ which is true since $\overrightarrow{u} \in A$ i.e. $3a-2b+7c=0$. Is this sufficient proof?

To show it is closed under addition I am unsure however...

Let $\overrightarrow{u} = (a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $\overrightarrow{v} = (a_2,b_2,c_2)$. Then $\overrightarrow{u} + \overrightarrow{v}  = (a_1 +a_2, b_1+b_2, c_1+c_2)$. How do I show that this vector is now in the subspace?

Comment: Can you try to verify that $3(a_1+a_2)-2(b_1+b_2)+7(c_1+c_2)=0$?

Comment: Since you seem to know how to add LaTeX formatting, why don't you use it everywhere you have formulae?

Comment: @AlexM. It doesn't make much difference does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\overrightarrow{u} = (a_1,b_1,c_1) \in A$ and $\overrightarrow{v} = (a_2,b_2,c_2) \in A$ we have $3a_1-2b_1+7c_1 = 0$ and $3a_2-2b_2+7c_2 = 0.$

For $\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v} = (a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2,c_1+c_2)$ we test for membership in $A$ by computing

$$3(a_1+a_2)-2(b_1+b_2)+7(c_1+c_2) = (3a_1-2b_1+7c_1)+(3a_2-2b_2+7c_2) = 0+0=0.$$

Therefore we do indeed have $\overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v} \in A$.